# @Min Annotation is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

My Entity Class property portion is given below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="rules")
public class Rule {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=4, max=128)
    @Column(length = 128, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String assetType;

    @Min(value=1, message="Minimum value should be 1")
    @Column(name = "min_quantity")
    private int min_quantity;

    @Min(value=1L, message="Minimum value should be 1")
    @Column
    private int warningAt;

    @Column
    private boolean status;
```

In html form:

```
<div class="has-error">
 <form:errors path="min_quantity" />
</div>
```

I am getting below error during form validator:

**"Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type int for property min_quantity; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: """**

**In my form its not showing my custom message.**

Comment: Cast string to Int

Comment: Could you describe in detail please?

Comment: Ok, show me the code first

Comment: And if you check your code you will find that `@Min` is NOTHING to do with the JPA API. It is the Bean Validation API (javax.validation).

Comment: I have already posted all of my necessary codes here,,,, Hibernate form validation problem...

Comment: NotEmpty annotation is working fine but Min annotation isn't working.. what's the problem?

Comment: In fact you haven't posted the necessary code at all. We don't know the value you're passnig to the entity. It seems your are trying to store a String in an int field

Answer (score 1):

@Min is applied to numbers not strings

Use

```
@Length(min = 1, message = "Minimum value should be 1")
```